# Calling adapters in "desktop" does not work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Using IBM MobileFirst 7.1

I have created a very simple hybrid project. Then added a very simple java adapter:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class BrokenAdapterResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hope keeps man alive....!";
    }
}
```

and also created a MobileFirst environment: "Desktop Browser web page". I try to call the adapter. When I call it from the "common" it works as expected. However when I call it from "desktop" it does not work:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
        "/adapters/BrokenAdapter/hello",
        WLResourceRequest.GET);



resourceRequest.send().then(
        function(result){
            var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))
            var message = data['responseText']
            $("#message").text(message) //Set the value in message div tag              
        },
        function(error){
            $("#message").text(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    );
```

In "common" I get the expected: `Hope keeps man alive....!` .
In the "desktop" I always get `{"status":200,"responseHeaders":{},"responseText":"undefined","errorCode":"API_INVOCATION_FAILURE","errorMsg":"Unsupported environment","invocationContext":null}`

I wonder what if wrong in this case? Is this the right way to call resources?

I have created a sample project that shows this thing https://hub.jazz.net/project/ignacio4d/BrokenProject/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/

specifically:

> MobileFirst applications can access resources using the
>   WLResourceRequest REST API. The REST API works with all adapters and
>   external resources, and is supported in the following hybrid
>   environments: iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8, and Windows 8.
>
> If your application supports other hybrid environments such as
>   BlackBerry, Mobile Web, or Desktop Browser, [see the tutorial for IBM
>   MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3](http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/).

In other words, Java adapters use WLResourceRequest. Java adapters do not support the Desktop Browser environment. A workaround would be to use JavaScript adapters which support both `WL.Client.invokeProceudre` and `WLResourceRequest`, so you can use regular `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` for the Desktop Browser environment.

Comment: The fact that Desktop Browser does not work with WResourceRequest, is that something temporal? I mean do you have plans to make it work?

Comment: @IdanAdar Does JAVA adapter support WL.Client.invokeProceudre ?