# MobileFirst 7.1 - MobileWebApp and DesktopBrowserApp Environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We are using MobileFirst 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201703150904 version. We have built a hybrid mobile application for iPhone and Android. In the backend, we have all Java Adapters.

Recently we have decided to extend the scope and add MobileWeb and DesktopBrowser Application. To achieve that I have created the new environment in eclipse studio and tried to test the new environments. I found this error "errorMsg":"Unsupported environment"

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324283/calling-adapters-in-desktop-does-not-work) where the same issue is discussed. The article states a workaround would be to use JavaScript adapters.

My question is how can we create these environments now, we only have Java adapters in the backend. Do we need to replicate all the adapters in JavaScript? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling adapters in "desktop" does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324283/calling-adapters-in-desktop-does-not-work)

Comment: Patbarron u are right my issue is close to that issue. But it's different, I have mentioned about that article in my question. As per that  Java adapters do not support the Desktop Browser environment. In my case all our adapter are Java based and we are live right now. As we are not in development phase how can we fix this issue. Do we need to rewrite all the adapters in JavaScript ?

Comment: The answer to the question you mentioned hasn't changed (though it was posted some time ago), and it seems to me you've asked basically the same question.  Java adapters are still not supported in the desktop browser environment.  Rewriting your adapters as JavaScript adapters would be one way to resolve the issue you're facing.

Comment: @patbarron Can you please confirm if Java Adapters is also not supported with MobileWebApp?

Comment: @patbarron How about MobileFirst version 8 does it support java adapter with Desktop or MobileWeb application?

Comment: I have not been able to find any statement in the documentation regarding the support of Java adapters in desktop browser apps, one way or the other. I will ask around.

Comment: In 7.1, Java adapters are also not supported for mobile web apps.  They're only supported on the list of platforms noted in the link included in that other question you referenced.

Comment: @patbarronThis was very surprising to me. I always believed MobileFirst is built once and can run on all the platforms including MobileWeb or Desktop. I understand that still works but rewriting adapters do not seems right to us. In fact in dev with eclipse we all use a browser with google chrome simulator, basically, we refer to the common package.  http://...common/1.0/default/index.html. So Technically this common package does exactly what we expect from MobileWeb or desktop. I mean I can even run the app in desktop mode and access the adapters with this common package with no issues.

Comment: @patbarron But this common package is disabled for remote servers(QA/UAT/PRD) so it does not serve my purpose. Not sure if there is a way to enable this.

Comment: "common" is really only intended to be used for development purposes.  The web resources in "common" are used generate environment-specific web resources (when they're not overriden by the developer in), and you can preview with it in the development environment.  Application preview is disabled on standalone servers, and the "common" environment isn't useful on standaone servers.

Comment: Also, there is at least one other feature on 7.1 that isn't available in web-based environments, and that is session-independent mode.  Applications deployed to a server where session-independent mode is enabled can't be used from a browser-based environment - I presume because supporting it requires more "smarts" on the client side than a web browser can reasonably provide.

Comment: Also, I can't explain at this moment why your Java adapter invocations work (apparently) correctly in common preview, and I'm not sure if it would work in all cases - I don't know the complete rationale behind Java adapters not working in browser-based environments, and I can not promise it would work in all cases, since we specifically document that it does not work.

Comment: @patbarron We are actually using Session mode. That won't be an issue for us.

Comment: @patbarron Did u find any updates regarding this issue. Will MobileFirst 8 solve our problem?

Comment: I have not found any more details on this question yet.